# PIL Image.open() cannot be opened for reading

Tags: python, file-io, python-imaging-library, ioerror

I have trouble reading an image file after it is received.

```
with open(fullpath, 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(filevalue)
f.close()

try:
    im = Image.open(fullpath, 'r')
    im = im.resize((28, 28))
    os.remove(fullpath)
    im.save(fullpath, 'PNG')
except:
    print 'Received non-image file, skipping...'
```

First open fullpath and write received filevalue, then close file. Now file is on disk.

After that, I open received file. I have checked this image file is not corrupted, and an independent python script can open it with PIL Image class. However, if I append open file code right after receiving, Error goes:

```
File xxxxxx.png could not be opened for reading
```

Since file has been written to disk, why can't I open it?

Comment: @paperfish Did you check the permission of the file.?

Comment: @mkHun Yes, this program has access. I made another copy and opened the file, it's ok. A temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made another copy of this file, and successfully opened it. It is a temporary solution, although lots of overhead. It seems that the file is locked even if I called f.close(), but not exiting the whole program.